# vs-code launch.json showing error for cpp debugger

Tags: c++, c, debugging, visual-studio-code

launch.json file for cpp debugging is showing error.
help me to rectify it

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      

      {
        "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
        "type": "by-gdb",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": true,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
          {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
          }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
      }
    ]
  }
```

---

It is showing 7 errors in it

```
Property args is not allowed.
Property stopAtEntry is not allowed.
Property environment is not allowed.
Property externalConsole is not allowed.
Property MIMode is not allowed.
Property miDebuggerPath is not allowed.
Property setupCommands is not allowed.
```

Comment: If you land here for the same reason I did, one additional reason for getting the error `Property args is not allowed.` is when the `request` is `attach` instead of `launch`. This makes perfect sense (the executable is already running in this use case) but I didn't find out immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Change `"type"` to `"cppdbg"`.

This isn't documented anywhere but half the [extra debugging properties](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_customizing-gdb-or-lldb) for C++ don't work if your type is not `"ccpdbg"` (if you're debugging gdb or lddb) or `"cppvsdbg"` if you're debugging with VS.

I ran into the same issue when using `"type": "lldb"`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after I switched to WSL2.

I needed to install the popular "C/C++" extension for Visual Studio Code.

The extension was before only enabled for the local machine.